# Alignment of products on home page in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

followed the code in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9 to Show products on homepage magento 1.9. But after that my products pages alignment is not proper!

BUT IF I DONT EDIT THE LAST PART OF LIST.PHTML
ALIGNMENT IS RIGHT BUT WITH AN ERROR
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\enhanced\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 188
lINE NUMBER 188 IS  $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();